# getApplicationContext to Activity CastException

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-context

I have to send `getApplicationContext` to a method, and in this method, I have to cast context to activity to use

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm)
```

But it show an exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity.

Why `getApplicationContext`?because I check my application update in main activity and don't want to limit it to an Activity (I want lifecycle).

How handle it?

**UPDATE**
I have `FN.java` that all static functions are here. one method job (`getUniqueID`) is to get device ID and screen width and height and etc. IN another hand, I have a `Update.java` that's for checking application update.
In this class, I use `getUniqueID`.
For using Update class in my main activity, I do it like :

```
if(updateInstance == null)
            updateInstance = new Update(getApplicationContext());
```

If I pass `this` instead of `getApplicationContext`, I know it's ok, but I want use `getApplicationContext` because maybe user click on some menu item and go to another activity or close application immediately; And I want to show notification Anyway.

Comment: are you casting the context into `Context`?

Comment: and/or are you using android's support libraries?

Comment: If you pass your application context to it you will not be able to cast to an Activity because it isn't a context from an activity. Please explain what you a little better so people may be able to suggest other approaches.

Comment: use  `your_activity_instance.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm)`

Comment: @thepoosh What you mean?! i do it like: public static String myMethod(Context context){Activity mActivity = (Activity)context;...

Comment: @GabrielNetto please see question again.updated.

Comment: @Dr.jacky, do you write `(Context)getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: Just a simple but ugly fix you may want to consider using a constructor that already receives the metrics along with the application context. Or make a setter for the property you want to have your width and height of the screen as set as you need.

Comment: @thepoosh Yes,i pass getApplicationContext to method in main activity

Comment: @Mr.Hyde did you problem get solved?

Comment: @Warpzit Yes. please see my answer. And if you have any problem, say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use

```
this
```

and everything works fine.

And for update check use singleton.